# What are Components involved to process a block chain transaction?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ethereum

I started studying blockchain. Can any one clarify some basic concepts. 
What is the difference in  mining node (miners), block and node in blockchain network.
When an end user initiate transaction who is the first component in blockchain who receives this request and this node forwards to whom and how ?
Question seems very basic but i am not finding exact answer. 
Please don't devote if question felt silly.

Comment: Hi SHAHID, is your question targeting to a specific platform, eg. hyperledger or ethereum? or both of them??

Comment: Hi @Isaac. Keeping it very general. You can use the reference of any platform.

Answer (score 0):

This answer generally uses Hyperledger Fabric as a reference for explaining different terms.

> What is the difference in mining node (miners), block and node in blockchain network

- A block is actually a unit in a blockchain that contains the value of an asset, a unique hash and a hash to its previous block in the chain. A block can also have one or more transactions. Each transaction contains a read-write set which modifies one or more key/value pairs (Asset values).
- Nodes are the communication entities of the blockchain. A “node” is only a logical function in the sense that multiple nodes of different types can run on the same physical server. What counts is how nodes are grouped in “trust domains” and associated to logical entities that control them.

There are three types of nodes:

1. Client or submitting-client: a client that submits an actual transaction-invocation to the endorsers, and broadcasts transaction-proposals to the ordering service.
2. Peer: a node that commits transactions and maintains the state and a copy of the ledger. Besides, peers can have a special endorser role.
3. Ordering-service-node or orderer: a node running the communication service that implements a delivery guarantee, such as atomic or total order broadcast..

The term mining / miners is referred in Public Blockchains such as Bitcoin. In Public Blockchain Networks, an end-user submits a transaction, which is verified (endorsed as authentic transaction) by majority of the nodes participating in the network. Specifically for Bitcoin network, all the nodes in the network compete to verify all the incoming transactions (termed as Proof-Of-Work) and the winning node is rewarded with an increase of balance in their crypto-wallets. This concept is called Mining.

However, in private or permissioned blockchains (such as Hyperledger), There's no Mining or Proof-Of-Work. Instead all the nodes participating in the network come to a state of agreement that a specific transaction is valid or invalid (termed as Consensus).

> When an end user initiate transaction who is the first component in blockchain who receives this request and this node forwards to whom and how ?

The answer depends on the underlying blockchain platform being used. For Hyperledger Fabric, Who will receive the request is decided by the endorsement policy as which and how many participating nodes are required to verify the transaction. For example, if the endorsement policy states that each peer from each organization should endorse a transaction, the request will be received by all the peers participating in the network. The peers validate the transaction and replies with an endorsement response containing the endorser signatures and the read/write sets of that transaction. When the client receives the endorsement response, it assembles the endorsements into a transaction and submits it to the ordering service node, which orders the transactions chronologically into blocks and deliver these blocks to all the peers in the network.

For Hyperledger Fabric, you can see the detailed and self explanatory Transaction Flow [Here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/txflow.html).